# How to encode a NFC chip with a website URL using a RC522 Module

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid

I am trying to encode a websites URL into my NFC chip, however, I don't have an android to write this data into the chip. I was wondering if the RC522 module can write an URL data into the chip so that it is readable by phone.

I know it needs to be URi type but I don't know if I could set this up using the RC522.

Comment: please read [ask]. Did you do any own research? Like reading the manuals?

Comment: See if this PC application supports your reader: Officially not listed to support RC522, but you can check it out: https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/nfc-readers/tagxplorer-pc-based-nfc-tag-reader-writer-tool:TAGXPLORER It allows writing the URI

Answer (score 1):

The MF RC522 is a reader IC, not a writer IC from NXP:
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/rfid+guide.pdf

There are some libraries for Arduino that you can use and write (only ISO 14443 A, not B) with an RC522 module - but they are limited and not every RFID-module is able to use it.

So, if you want a good library for the RC522, check this:
https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid

And this is the code:

```
mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(blockNumber, bytes, bytesLen);
```

Where the block number is a number from 0 to 15, bytes your array and byteslen the length of your array.

You can find a complete tutorial here: https://lastminuteengineers.com/how-rfid-works-rc522-arduino-tutorial/

To write a link in this TAG, you can put a link as text (not the good way) or you can write the TAG as "well known type", using an identifier type (like "https://" or "http://" as code). To this, you have to format your NFC with the NDEF format. Check this tutorial for more info:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/ndef

As said, the RC522 is really limited and you will probably fail to write a right formatted NDEF message on you NFC chip.

If you have the possibility, try to upgrade your module to a PN532 IC. This is also really old, but the most used in the Arduino world.